# Release/Remove App permissions on Logout in Android

Tags: android, android-security

I have been developing an App which needs permissions for Location, Camera and has a user login. Lately, noticed that on Logout and re-login, the App does not ask for permissions because App permissions are global. Now, my question is

> Can we release/remove the App permissions on Logout so that we save on space and have better security. Any comments or pointers to documentation is helpful.

Comment: nothing to do with android studio, seeing as that is just what you use to develop your app, no need to include it if you're not asking about a feature of the ide itself, but still, this is an interesting question, i doubt there would be a way to do this if you don't have a system level app